# How to display a tooltip only if the mouse cursor is within certain coordinates?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Within my component, I'm drawing some rectangles as below:

```
                var objGraphics:Graphics=graphics;
                objGraphics.drawRect(start, end, total, 5);
                objGraphics.endFill();
```

I need to display a custom tooltip for each rectange when the mouse cursor is hovering over it.

How can I do this? I'm using the MouseMove event to track when the cursor moves over these coordinates (that part is working), but when I change the tooltip text it's not refreshing.

```
private function this_MOUSE_MOVE(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
//...some code to check the coordinates to find out which rectangle the cursor 
//is over   
        //current tooltip is "Rectangle A";
        ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(_myToolTip);
        var localPoint:Point=new Point(event.localX, event.localY);
        var globalPoint:Point=new Point(localToGlobal(localPoint).x, 
    localToGlobal(localPoint).y);
        //cursor is over Rectangle B, so changing the tooltip;
        _myToolTip=ToolTipManager.createToolTip("Rectangle B", 
    globalPoint.x, globalPoint.y) as ToolTip;
        callLater(addChild, [_myToolTip]);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: The problem seems to be with the following line:

```
ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(_myToolTip);
```

If I comment out the preceding line, it will display the new tooltip, but it will keep creating new ones and the old ones never get removed. But if I add that line, it doesn't add any tooltips! Is the code not being executed sequentially, i.e., is the code to remove the tooltip somehow getting executed after the code to add the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming what you're adding to the stage, is called "myShape", you could do something like this:

```
// in your class...
private var var tooltip:Tooltip;  // Or whatever your tooltip is

myShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleOver);
myShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleOut);

private function handleOver(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Show here
    // OR
    // tooltip = new Tooltip();
    // addChild(tooltip);

}

private function handleOut(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Hide here
    // OR
    // removeChild(tooltip);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @[True North Creative] Thanks! I will try this out.

Comment: @[True North Creative] I tried removing & re-adding the tooltip, but it didn't refresh (I've shown my code in the question). Could you please show how you did it?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=tooltips_3.html

Comment: @[True North Creative] It's exactly the same concept, but my rectangles are just drawn rectangles (graphics.drawRect()) not objects, so I can't directly set tooltip properties on them. What I'm trying to do is check the coordinates of the cursor within the MouseMove event handler and then refresh the tooltip with the text for that particular rectangle. I'm successfully able to detect if the cursor is within a given rectangle, but I'm not able to change the tooltip.

Comment: Are you able to at least add the tooltips - just not update them?

Comment: @[True North Creative] Yes, The problem seems to be when I remove the tooltip: ToolTipManager.destroyToolTip(_myToolTip); If I comment that out, it will display the new tooltip, but it will keep creating new ones and the old ones never get removed. But if I add that line, it doesn't add any tooltips! Is the code not being executed sequentially, i.e., is the code to remove the tooltip somehow getting executed after the code to add the tooltip?

Comment: I would separate those two (destroy and create) into separate functions. For testing, set a class variable like _isTooltipCreated = false;  First, on mouse out-destroy the tooltip - and set _isTooltipCreated = false; and your mouseover function conditionally create the tooltip if _isTooltipCreated == false (also set it to true after you created a tooltip successfully).  Something to try.

Comment: @[True North Creative] The problem is that it is a single component with no child objects. The "rectangles" are just drawn graphics. So, the mouse_over and mouse_out functions get called only once when the user hovers over the component and hovers out of the component. To get it to check the cursor location everytime the mouse is moved within the component, I need to use the mouse_out function. I'm not sure how I can check _isTooltipCreated with this.

Comment: This might help you:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff6.html

Comment: I think the problem lies in the mouse_move.  I would listen for that on mouse enter (to move the tooltip with it) or better yet, just update the position of it.

Comment: @[True North Creative] That's a great resource! Thanks! I have a feeling this might work.

Comment: @[True North Creative] Thanks a lot! It worked. I dispatched an event and set the text of the tooltip within that event as described in your article.